# Script de plsql no devuelve nada

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: Script no devuelve nada]
[image: DataGrid vacía]

Tengo un problema con este script ya que tengo la base de datos llena pero al ejecutar lo siguiente el cursos no devuelve nada

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR VA_QUERY IS
    SELECT Business_Area_Cd , Business_Area_Name FROM EXMCPRA.BUSINESS_AREA;

 SALIDA VA_QUERY%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
 OPEN VA_QUERY;
        FETCH VA_QUERY INTO SALIDA;      
         dbms_output.put_line (SALIDA.Business_Area_Cd || ',' || SALIDA.Business_Area_Name );
 CLOSE VA_QUERY;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR VA_QUERY IS
    SELECT Business_Area_Cd , Business_Area_Name FROM EXMCPRA.BUSINESS_AREA;

 SALIDA VA_QUERY%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
 OPEN VA_QUERY;
 LOOP
        FETCH VA_QUERY INTO SALIDA; 
        EXIT WHEN VA_QUERY%NOTFOUND;        
            dbms_output.put_line (SALIDA.Business_Area_Cd || ',' || SALIDA.Business_Area_Name );
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE VA_QUERY;

END;
```